# Freetype Code Signing Error (Xcode 7.1) App Upload Issue

Tags: macos, xcode, mac-appstore, development, code-signing

I'm wondering if anyone can fix my problem? I'm trying to upload a project to the App Store. I'm using Xcode 7.1. I'm getting the following error related to code-signing freetype.

```
CodeSign /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFML_App -xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug/SFML_App.app
cd /Users/me/Documents/cplusplus/sfml/SFML_App
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

Signing Identity:     "Mac Developer: me (xxxxxxxxxx)"

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --timestamp=none /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFML_App-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug/SFML_App.app

/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFML_App-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug/SFML_App.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFML_App-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug/SFML_App.app/Contents/Frameworks/freetype.framework
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Any Ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This question would attract more answers on [StackOverflow](https://www.StackOverflow.com]) because it involves software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests a subcomponent is not signed. Use the `--deep` flag with [`codesign`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html):

> `--deep`
>
> When signing a bundle, specifies that nested code content such as helpers, frameworks, and
>   plug-ins, should be recursively signed in turn. Beware that all signing options you specify
>   will apply, in turn, to such nested content.
>   When verifying a bundle, specifies that any nested code content will be recursively verified as
>   to its full content. By default, verification of nested content is limited to a shallow inves-tigation investigation
>   tigation that may not detect changes to the nested code.
>   When displaying a signature, specifies that a list of directly nested code should be written to
>   the display output. This lists only code directly nested within the subject; anything nested
>   indirectly will require recursive application of the codesign command.

Apple's [Technical Note 2206: OS X Code Signing in Depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html) provides more insight.

Comment: Good to hear. Please could you [mark this question as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I still can't upload to the App Store. whenever i try i get the following error:

An error occurred during validation

    Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for A.   is this still related to freetype?

Comment: Please can you ask a new question for this. Feel free to mention the question's link in the comments to help others link the two questions.

Comment: new question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219349/mac-app-store-upload-fail-validation-error-cfbundlesupportedplatforms-or-mach